# Magento (1.7) Bundled Product with FREE Product Option

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, bundled-product, free-gift

I'm looking to create a bundle offer where customers can buy two items from a collection (30 products with varying prices) and they get a fixed third item which is a FREE product.

As the final price will vary depending on what the customer chooses, how do I make the basket subtotal add the two items but ignore the third priced item?

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Since the third item is fixed, you can use shopping cart price rules:

- if cart contains at least two items of category X
- then add product Y as a gift

However you need a small extension for the "add product as a gift" action in shopping cart price rules:

You can get it for free here: https://github.com/code4business/freeproduct

It adds a new shopping cart price rules action "free product" where you can enter qty and sku.

[image: screenshot admin]

These products are added to the cart as non editable items with price 0 during sales rule validation.

[image: screenshot cart]

#### How it works

- A new rule type is added to the sales rule form, in an observer on `adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform`
- An observer on `salesrule_validator_process` processes the new rule type. It adds the configured SKU to the cart and sets a custom price of 0 and a custom option that identifies the product as free gift.
- Another observer on `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` removes existing gift items from the cart (that's what the custom option from before is for), before the rules are processed.
- The cart item template is adjusted to remove qty input and "remove" link from gift items (they would not work anyways).

***Disclaimer: I was involved in the development of this extension.***